# Octave interpret loop variable differently?

Tags: variables, for-loop, octave

Can someone explain why this is happening

`disp(sprintf('Value of i = %d\n', i));` and

`disp(sprintf('Value of i = %d\n', i**i));` are interpreted differently in below code!

```
octave:1> load monk.dat 
octave:2> whos
Variables in the current scope:

   Attr Name        Size                     Bytes  Class
   ==== ====        ====                     =====  ===== 
        x          10x10                       800  double

Total is 100 elements using 800 bytes

octave:3> for i=x(:,1),
> disp(sprintf('Value of i = %d\n', i));
> end;
Value of i = 0.330077
Value of i = 0.00601253
Value of i = 0.0864004
Value of i = 0.145695
Value of i = 0.999297
Value of i = 0.170224
Value of i = 0.609515
Value of i = 0.435406
Value of i = 0.454971
Value of i = 0.153091

octave:4> for i=x(:,1),
> disp(sprintf('Value of i = %d', i**i));
> end;
error: can't do A ^ B for A and B both matrices
```

Comment: monkwoo: ì` is a vector inside your loop, not a scalar

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop iterates over the columns of the matrix given. Sadly, this is hidden because the `sprintf` function here repeats the template until it exhausts the data given. Consider the following:

```
>> for i=(1:5)', i, end
i =
   1
   2
   3
   4
   5

>> for i=(1:5), i, end
i =  1
i =  2
i =  3
i =  4
i =  5
```

As you can see, in the first case, with a column vector, it only loops once, with `i` equal to the full column vector. In the second case it loops once for each element in the row vector.

The reason you didn't notice this:

```
>> sprintf('Value of i = %d\n', (1:5))
ans = Value of i = 1
Value of i = 2
Value of i = 3
Value of i = 4
Value of i = 5
```

`sprintf` repeated the template 5 times, once for each element in the second argument.